# a beginner's puzzle about the source code of += method of ListBuffer class in Scala

Tags: scala

`ListBuffer` could efficiently append an element to its end and then be converted to a `List`.

I studied the source code of `ListBuffer`'s append method (`+=`), but found it difficult to understand its workings. The detailed source code is [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#L1).

An excerpted source code:

```
final class ListBuffer[A] extends AbstractBuffer[A] {
  private var start: List[A] = Nil
  private var last0: ::[A] = _
  private var exported: Boolean = false
  private var len = 0

  def += (x: A): this.type = {
    if (exported) copy()
    if (isEmpty) {
      last0 = new :: (x, Nil)
      start = last0
    } else {
      val last1 = last0     // last1 is a local variable, is it necessary here?
      last0 = new :: (x, Nil)
      last1.tl = last0      // 
    }
    len += 1
    this
   }
}
```

In the `else` part, a local variable `last1` is defined and afterwards constructed to contain several elements at the end. The `last0` is always pointed to the last cell.

So is `last1` necessary here? After-all, it will be out of scope after the blocking. I can't understand why the author has to define `last1` here.

Answer (score 2):

Well,

```
  val last1 = last0     // last1 is a local variable, is it necessary here?
  last0 = new :: (x, Nil)
  last1.tl = last0      //
```

As you can see, it is indeed used to change `.tl` *after* we've changed `last0`.

What's `.tl` for then?

```
@SerialVersionUID(509929039250432923L) // value computed by serialver for 2.11.2, annotation added in 2.11.4
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

As you can see, class `::` isn't really immutable: there's a reference to the rest of the list which can be changed, which is exactly what the last line does.

Now why would you need to change that after changing `last0`? That's because we need a temporary variable to keep the newly created last element, and we need to assign `last0` to that element, anyway — so we just reassign `last0` and create the new last element in one go, and linking the old last element (held in `last1`) after.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Still confusing. Why "we need a temporary variable to hold the newly created last element"? `last0 = new :: (x, Nil)` would store the last cell in a class field of `last0`. But `last1` is just a local variable, it disappears after the `else` code block.

Comment: It's not enough to move `last0`; you also need the now-penultimate element's `tl` to point at the element just created. So `last0.tl = new :: (x, Nil); last0 = last0.tl` would do just fine, using `tl` instead of `last1`. The choice between the two is a matter of taste and/or performance tests.

Comment: I found this implementation of `+=` method has some problem. The appended elements could not be saved to `start` list. Here is an execution demo: (1) `val t = new ListBuffer[Int]`; (2) `t+=1` //{`start=List(1)`, `last0=List(1)`}; (3) `t+=2`; {`start=List(1)`, `last0=List(1)`} (4) `t.toList` {`List(1)`}.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is essentially

```
last0.ti = new :: (x, Nil)  // put new element x at end of list
```

Except there's a problem with this reduction: `last0` always needs to "point at" the end.  So `last1` becomes a temporary reference to end of the list so that `end-of-the-list.t1` can be accessed and a new end-of-the-list can be added.

Answer (score 0):

So there's 3 lines.

last1 will point to the current last0.

last0 is set to the new last element.

last1.t1 is set to last0.

last1 isn't a new object. It simply points to the current last one.
t1 I assume is the classes pointer to its next element.
So what its doing is pointing the current last element to the new element.

This can be confusing in scala since it uses mutables and vars which are avoided if possible in scala.